# Intered object with one reference? Does scope apply to interened objects?

Tags: java

1. Is the String object holding the value "dog" still considered interned even if zero is the only variable referencing to it?

   ```
   String zero = "dog";
   ```
2. How many objects are in this code?
   Either there's 1 because interned objects ignore scope, or there's 2 because scope still applies.

   ```
   String jack = "skellington";

   for(//stuff)
   {
   String sally = "skellington";
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

String literals are always interned i.e pool is created for them. If after decalring one string literal, that are referenced anywhere for that instance of JVM, that will be picked from pool only

1)One object will be created. Does not matter if it is referenced down the line or not

2)one object will be created

see intern method at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: So it is correct to say the object created in my 1st case is interned even if it only has one reference(zero) ?

Answer (score 1):

> How many objects are in this code? Either there's 1 because interned
>   objects ignore scope, or there's 2 because scope still applies.

Since java interns the String literals in a Stringpool for the given application so ***there will be Only one object created for your code***. Look at [String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) as specified in Java Language specification. It says following points about String literals:

> - **Literal strings within the same class (§8) in the same package (§7) represent references to the same String object (§4.3.1).**
> - Literal strings within different classes in the same package represent references to the same String object.
> - Literal strings within different classes in different packages likewise represent references to the same String object.
> - Strings computed by constant expressions (§15.28) are computed at compile time and then treated as if they were literals.
> - Strings computed by concatenation at run time are newly created and therefore distinct.
> - The result of explicitly interning a computed string is the same string as any pre-existing literal string with the same contents.

Comment: I was resisting so hard to ask about the 3rd bullet point because I thought people would think it's a dumb question, but you answered it before I even asked :)

Comment: Yeah..I know that's why I put forward all points before you... :)